# Event when application gets installed (Android)

Tags: java, android

Is there any event triggered when the application is finished installed in the phone.I have seen some post but no luck ,there were similar question asked but no answer was found.
Any help would be appreciated.
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No you can't, the user has to explicitly start your application.

You can always check for the first time your application is launched.

Comment: Technically (in terms) this is not correct, because there is the ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED broadcast, which already installed applications can listen to.

Comment: Indeed, but in the context of this question it was correct. To quote the documentation: "Note that the newly installed package does not receive this broadcast.". I inferred that the OP was talking an application receiving a broadcast action once it has been installed ("when **the** application is finished installed" and not **an** application)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to check if your application has to do the installation tasks or not is to check your SharedPreferences when your main Activity is created. As your app has not run before, you're preferences will be empty:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
if (!prefs.contains(FIRST_RUN_KEY)) {
   prefs.edit().putBoolean(FIRST_RUN_KEY,false).commit();
   // TODO Do stuff that should be done at the first run
}
```

Comment: What if android:allowBackup="true"  ?